# FindBugs detects the SIC_INNER_SHOULD_BE_STATIC_ANON warning for the following code

Tags: java, findbugs, spotbugs

FindBugs detects the SIC_INNER_SHOULD_BE_STATIC_ANON warning for the following code.
Besides ignoring warnings in SuppressFBWarnings
How can I avoid SIC_INNER_SHOULD_BE_STATIC_ANON?

```
Class MyClass $ 1 may be able to be refactored into a named static inner class.
Local variable name reference
```

```java
public class MyClass() {

    public Map<String, String> fromJSON(String json) throws Exception {
            TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> reference = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {};
            Map<String, String> map = null;
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            map = mapper.readValue(json, reference);

        return map;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the message, you can create a named static inner class:

```
private static final class MyTypeReference extends TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> {}

public Map<String, String> fromJSON(String json) throws Exception {
    TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> reference = new MyTypeReference();
    ...
}
```

BTW the [FindBugs is not updated for years](https://mailman.cs.umd.edu/pipermail/findbugs-discuss/2016-November/004321.html) so it is better to replace it with [its successor](https://mailman.cs.umd.edu/pipermail/findbugs-discuss/2017-September/004383.html) or other solutions such as PMD, Google Error prone, etc.